# Python regex behaves unexpectedly on cygwin

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, cygwin, x86-64

### Problem:

I'm trying to extract the **body** of html pages using Python.
On the face of it - it's almost trivial (viz.:

```
'<body.*?>(.*)</body>', re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
```

Indeed, several [online regex verifiers](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=online%20python%20regex%20verifyers&oq=online%20python%20regex%20verifyers&aqs=chrome..69i57.19523j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=online%20python%20regex%20verifier) confirmed the validity of the above.
However, when I tried to run the following script in my environment, the match is a *NoneType*. Any ideas?

### Test script:

```
#!/bin/env python

import re
import urllib2

def display_html(f):
    print f.read()

def get_body(text):
    p = re.compile('<body.*?>(.*)</body>', re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    print p, type(p)
    m = p.match(text)
    print m, type(m)

def get_html_text(url):
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return f

def to_text(f):
    return f.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "http://www.ibm.com/us/en/" # A nicely formatted known page
    f = get_html_text(url) 
    html_text = to_text(f)
    body = get_body(html_text)
```

### Output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0xffe245c0> <type '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>
None <type 'NoneType'>
```

### My Environment:

Python 2.7.3, CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.22(0.268/5/3) 2013-07-22 17:06 i686 Cygwin, Windows 7 x86-64.

Comment: I get the same result on a Mac, it's not specific to Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression is fine. There's no `<body>` tag in that web page. Instead of a body, it has `<frameset>`.

You need to use `re.search`, not `re.match`. The latter tries to match the regexp at the beginning of the string.

Comment: You obviously made no attempt to debug the problem yourself -- how could you not look at the raw data?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Barmar.
However, if I look in the source code of the current page (`view-source:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497081/python-regex-behaves-unexpectedly-on-cygwin`) I see it has a `<body>` stanza, and plugging this into my URL, still produces _NoneType_.

Comment: I actually been trying to debug it with several URLs, which their source _had_ <body> stanzas. When I tried above script in my cygwin, on pages that I could see <body> in their source, I would always get _NoneType_.

Comment: Same thing happens for me on Mac and Linux. Now I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for pointing out that I needed to use _re.search_ and  not _re.match_.